# easy-rsa v3: execute build-ca and gen-req silently?

Tags: ubuntu

With the newer v3 version of easy-rsa I could not find a way to silently feed data to the command line:

```
$ ./easyrsa build-ca nopass

Note: using Easy-RSA configuration from: ./vars
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
...............................................................................................................................................................+++
...............................................................................+++
writing new private key to '~/EasyRSA-3.0.4/pki/private/ca.key.Dz9CBy9xV1'
-----
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Common Name (eg: your user, host, or server name) [Easy-RSA CA]:
```

I've tried fiddling with the files `openssl-easyrsa.cnf` and `vars` but to no avail.

I'm automating these operations inside a docker container entrypoint which is why I can't go with anything interactive.

Answer (score 20):

Okay, that was as simple as doing this before running easyrsa:

```
# export EASYRSA_BATCH=1
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried `set_var EASYRSA_BATCH "yes"` in the `vars` file, but that didn't work. Running `export EASYRSA_BATCH=1` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it did not work when you...

`set EASYRSA_BATCH "yes"`

Is that you have to:

`set it to EASYRSA_BATCH "1"`.

It worked for me.